# deploy twilio react plugin throws error: The requested resource /Configuration was not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, twilio

I am doing this tutorial:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/quickstart/getting-started-plugin

I have a twilio trial account. I have a react plugin that I wanted to deploy. Hitting `npm run deploy` would throw me the following error:

> Request get to Configuration failed with status 404 and message The
>   requested resource /Configuration was not found

Answer (score 1):

This error message tells you that the account that you are using doesn't contain an enabled Flex instance. You probably skipped [this step](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/quickstart/getting-started-plugin#login-to-your-twilio-flex-application-via-twilio-cli) and didn't log in to the CLI with the newly created Flex account.

You can add a new profile to the CLI with `twilio profiles:create`, while supplying the new account SID and auth token from the console.

Once you have done that, you can either use this profile with the parameter `--profile`:

```
twilio flex:plugins:deploy --major --changelog "Adding Bing as search engine" --description "First Plugin on Flex" \n
--profile Flex
```

or make the profile the default and use the command as instructed in the tutorial:

```
twilio profiles:use flex
twilio flex:plugins:deploy --major --changelog "Adding Bing as search engine" --description "First Plugin on Flex"
```

Comment: I had done the twilio login step, but was missing the `--profile profile-name` step. Once I did this I was unblocked. Wish the instructions had that!